# Use SUMIFS in an ArrayFormula Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-query

I've already seen a lot of topics about my problem, but I can't resolve it.
Actually, I don't understand what is wrong in my formula ?

```
=ArrayFormula(
    IF(
        ISBLANK(A6:A);;SUMIFS(
            Sheet1!J:J;
            Sheet1!K:K; ">="&A6:A;
            Sheet1!K:K;"<="& EOMONTH(A6:A;0)
        )
    )
)
```

What I'm trying to do :
Each line is a month. I want to SUM all sales made between the first day on the month, and the last one.

If I don't use ArrayFormula, it works. I dont understand how to write this formula to work with ArrayFormula.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Do you have a sample sheet? If not can you create one

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice . Here's the sample sheet (with few data) : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ux_7jXetCPBajZ9Mx1hBXUPkNEVJUl-tYTDMjyxJTP8/copy

Comment: hey buddy, just had a look at your Formula and it works for me? are you trying to understand how arrays work? you could also work out this answer by using a google query

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice for your answer. Yes, I'm trying to transform XXX formulas into one ArrayFormula. I don't succeed to do it because my formula must include ranges... and I don't how how tu use ranges with ArrayFormula.

Comment: Maybe with a query it would be easier ?

Comment: Yes, you'r right. In the sample document I've linked in my previous message, I'm trying to add a query function (cell E4). But I didn't succeed... Can you help me ?
`=query(B:B;"select B, where A > '"&E3&"'";-1)")"`

Comment: try this =query(A:B;"Select B where A > date '"&text(eomonth(A3;0);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
basically google query struggles with datetime syntax, so you need to add in some added extras which always trip me up! you can make the where clause as complex as you like as you have access to all of the google/excel like formulas as well as SQL

Answer (score 1):

Just adding this as an answer for you,

Instead of using an array formula, I believe a query would serve you better.

as google date-time syntax is tricky we first have to convert the date value into a text and parse it as "yyyy-mm-dd" we then wrap the EOMONTH to get the last day of the month.

so we use the following formula to get the sum of the months sales:

```
    =query(A:B;"Select sum(B) 

where A <= date '"&text(eomonth(E14;0);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 

AND A >= date '"&text(E14;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' label sum(B) ''  ";0)
```

hopefully, this is what you were after, apologies for the delay was on the train!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ygppZZCd4b_Y_HufLwLdcynHAsa3pn6z5YXb3Poc3vk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for the query function @Datanovice ! Now, I'm trying to convert your formula into an ArrayFormula. I tried to do this in your Google Sheets document, but I failed. So I tried to do this with other formulas (FILTER and SUMIFS), but I failed too... Is it impossible to use ArrayFormula in this case ? See your document : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ygppZZCd4b_Y_HufLwLdcynHAsa3pn6z5YXb3Poc3vk/edit#gid=0
Thanks a lot !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I think I wasn't enough clear... I want to expand automatically the SUMIFS function, without copying it in the whole range. 
In the sheet example, there are only 4 months. But in my real sheet, I have 20 years of data, and each month, there's a new month to add. I would like to write the formula just in the first cell of the sheet, and Google Sheets fills automatically each month.
That's why I would like to do the job with an ArrayFormula. It's a bad idea ?

Comment: You could just expand the query to reference the whole range? Try adding new data it will add it automatically

Comment: I prefer use an ArrayFormula instead copy-paste my formula (or expand) because the number of rows will change continually.

Comment: It isn't possible to use an ArrayFormula with SUMIFS, or QUERY or FILTER when you have to deal with ranges ? See here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ygppZZCd4b_Y_HufLwLdcynHAsa3pn6z5YXb3Poc3vk/edit#gid=0

ArrayFormula should work with a query function, or sumifs or filter, no ?
Thanks !